# returning List<string> from JSON call in Jquery has undefined length

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am making a call to a webservice from jquery and trying to return an List (I have also tried a string[]). When I get the results back I can see it holds an array with the  values I need, but I can not iterate through them in Javascript because there is no length value.

my C# Webservice is as follows:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string[] GetMultiChoiceOptions(int keyId)
    {
        string connectionString = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SitesUtil db = new SitesUtil(connectionString);
        List<MultiChoiceOption> keys = db.GetMultiChoiceOptions(keyId, 1); //TO DO CHANGE THIS TO REAL USERID

        return keys.Select(a => a.OptionValue).ToArray();
    }
```

and My Jquery/javscript call is as follows:

```
function GetKeys(keyid) {

    var pageUrl = '<%=ResolveUrl("~/WebService/UpdateDatabase.asmx")%>'
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: pageUrl + "/GetMultiChoiceOptions",
        data: '{keyId:' + keyid + '}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: GetKeysSuccessCall,
        error: OnErrorCall
    });
}

function GetKeysSuccessCall(response) {
    /* TO DO */
    var i = 0;
    for (i =0; i < response.length; i++) {
        $("#popupList").append('<li>' + response[i] + '</li>');                
        }       
}
```

I'm not sure how I deal with an array without a length in javascript?

Comment: shouldn't it be response.length?

Comment: it should be, but it is undefined..

Comment: You should show what it is returning your web service as a response

Comment: If it is an object, you need `for in` object iteration or $.each instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-javascript-object-ie-associative-array

Comment: @michael Use Stackoverflow's searchbox next time!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use Google Console. Best and helpful.

To see what you receive, use `console.log(response);` (instead of alert and do NOT use in IE because it doesn't know console)

try first of all

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: pageUrl + "/GetMultiChoiceOptions",
        data: '{keyId:' + keyid + '}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response){
          GetKeysSuccessCall(response);
        },
        error: function(msg) {
           OnErrorCall(msg);
         }
    });
```

And **one** more :

```
function GetKeysSuccessCall(response) {
    /* TO DO */
    var i = 0;
    for (i =0; i < response.length; i++) {
        $("#popupList").append('<li>' + response[i] + '</li>');                
        }       
}
```

repsonse must be instead of `item`

Comment: I will try this.. but i am using firebug, and I know im getting an object back with 4 strings, like I want.. but the object does not have a length property

Comment: resposne from function argument !!! not `item`. That's why the error occured because length is not property of NULL

Comment: Internet Explorer has a console object if you open the Developer Tools first (which you'd need to do to see the output anyway), so there's no reason you couldn't do the same thing in IE.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use first of all the **JSONSerializer** to send the rigth json structure to the client.

You should return only a string, which has the JSON format, and then it will work!

Answer (score 1):

I cant explain why it works, but what I needed to do was get the response.d value....

So this was the solution in the end:

```
function GetKeysSuccessCall(response) {
    /* TO DO */
    var result = response.d;

    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
    {
        $("#popupList").append('<li>' + result[i] + '</li>');         
    }
}
```

(if someone can explain where the .d comes from?)

Comment: it is simply a security feature that Microsoft added in ASP.NET 3.5’s version of ASP.NET AJAX. By encapsulating the JSON response within a parent object, the framework helps protect against a particularly nasty XSS vulnerability. I think if you see my answer to the .each i used response.GetMultiChoiceOptionsResult; which has the same effect

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .each function like so

```
   success: function (response) {
            var options= response.d;
            $.each(options, function (index, option) {
                $("#popupList").append('<li>' + response[option] + '</li>'); 

            });
        },
```

or

```
function GetKeysSuccessCall(response) {
    /* TO DO */
    var i = 0;
    for (i =0; i < response.d.length; i++) {
        $("#popupList").append('<li>' + response.d[i] + '</li>');                
        }       
}
```

Comment: I just updated my answer to include result on the end of GetMultiChoiceOptions, so that its GetMultiChoiceOptionsResult

Comment: I cant test this because im not t work.. but I thought the jquery $.each method used the length property.. of which is undefined so i didnt think that would work.. Also the second answer i have already tried but response.length is undefined

Comment: first option. var options= response.GetMultiChoiceOptionsResult;  options is undefined. Second option response.length is undefined